# OpenCV DFT function give different between C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I am using the OpenCV DFT function to calculate the Fourier transform of the image and I found the different results between python code and C++ code (test with the same image).
Following is the code snippet:

C++ code:

```
Mat image = imread("sample_image_path", IMREAD_COLOR);
float ratio = (float) image.cols / 500;
cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(500, (float) image.rows / ratio));
cv::Mat frame;
cv::cvtColor(image, frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat fImage;
frame.convertTo(fImage, CV_32F);

cv::Mat fourierTransform;
dft(fImage, fourierTransform,cv::DFT_SCALE|cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
```

Python code:

```
image = cv2.imread("sample_image_path")
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image_float32 = np.float32(image)

dft = cv2.dft(image_float32, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE|cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
```

And these are the DFT result from those codes:
C++ result:

```
(2.87114e+07,0)
(-235565,-185356)
(83053.5,-133853)
(325047,-35144.2)
(15266.2,73630.8)
(10694.3,23623.2)
(66154.5,9108.8)
(-66126.1,31.8135)
(-59579.2,47464.7)
(-65894.7,-48799.3)
(-38388.1,-34958.9)
(11532.8,-24410.8)
(-73011.9,-17565.3)
(-45435.4,-59388.7)
(-56091.8,-71480.4)
(-58590.1,-35274.9)
(-75216,-38256.6)
(-47855.7,-27994)
(-18011,-15732.5)
```

Python result:

```
[28730282.        0.]
[-235971.77 -185170.42]
[  83683.805 -134241.84 ]
[325126.44  -34884.383]
[14188.441 74207.67 ]
[11826.884 23862.877]
[66535.41   9581.168]
[-66173.336      -88.09851]
[-59670.54   48255.867]
[-66266.734 -47755.05 ]
[-38385.45 -35405.57]
[ 11244.034 -23841.91 ]
[-72588.35 -18074.01]
[-45237.465 -59732.125]
[-56079.074 -71814.05 ]
[-59240.047 -35828.914]
[-75450.53  -38459.656]
[-47249.344 -28013.852]
[-18490.021 -16484.36 ]
...
```

which is completely different
It seems to me, that there is something wrong with DFT function.
Any idea about why do I have this difference result between these two?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you have checked that DFT imputs are equal  in both cases? Note that the first output corresponds to the sum of all inputs (with maybe some normalisation). This provides a simple first debug check.

Comment: Do you get different results on the un-resized images?

Comment: @WilliamMiller, Yes event resize or none resize, the result is always different.